# what if range of normalized of data in machine learning goes beyond?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, normalization, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

[image]Normalization in machine learning is the process of translating data into the range 0 -> 1 or -1 -> 1. What if the values goes above 1 or below -1. What does that mean?  Is it again an outlier? If this scenario happens when normalizing the labels, will it help to improve the accuracy of the prediction?

Comment: Giving us an understanding of the data is appreciated. Using images of data tables takes up more space than is necessary. Please consider formatting an example using a markdown table instead. This can be done with a variety of tools to minimize the labour of this, including: https://tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example with normalizing to $[0,1]$.

We achieve this by transforming the original data in a particular way:

$$
Data_{[0,1]} = \dfrac{
Data - Data_{min}
}{
Data_{max} - Data_{min}
}
$$

If you apply this transformation, all of your $Data$ points will be mapped to $[0,1]$. The only way to go outside of that interval is by applying that transformation to a new point. If a new point is mapped to a value exceeding $1$, it means that it is greater than the greatest point in the $Data$. If a new point is mapped to a value below $0$, it means that it is smaller than than the smaller point in the $Data$.

Comment: This is the equation to transform raw data into normalized form. Also, not always the normalized data comes under this range. I have set of normalized data(extracted from activities of few participants) where there exists data greater than the upper threshold value and lesser than lower threshold value. Those values are valid and required to be considered while creating the model as it determines the error created by the subjects which gradually affects the performance evaluation. So what are such data really called and how it should be handled while creating a machine learning model?

Comment: @Krishna How do you have data greater than the largest data point?

Comment: I have added an image with the question. Please have a look. The screenshot was took after transforming raw data into normalized form. Also, thank you for your response.

Comment: @Krishna So how do you have data greater than the largest data point? Are you applying the equation I gave, or are you subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation?